# Azure Function app with event hub trigger stops randomly from consuming event hub message

Tags: azure, azure-functions, timeout, azure-eventhub

All of sudden, Azure Function app with event hub trigger stopped consuming messages/events from partition. Restarting the function app mitigated the issue.

What would be possible reason?

It is happen on different partition on different time and no particular pattern observed?

host.json as below

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "eventHubs": {
      "batchCheckpointFrequency": 5,
        "maxEventBatchSize": 10,
        "prefetchCount": 300
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Warning"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "-1"
}
```

Comment: This isn't something that can likely be resolved on Stack Overflow, as it will require digging into logs generated and, quite likely working to find a minimal repro.  I'd suggest opening an issue in the Azure SDK repository.  That will give us a better chance to gather the needed context for assistance.   
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/new/choose

Comment: @JesseSquire, as suggested reported issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/37753